# Including class from header file in Eclipse C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, class, header, include

Very new to C++. I'm having trouble including a class and function from my header file into my cpp file. I've double checked everything and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, maybe the format for eclipse is different from the guide I am following? If anyone can help it's very appreciated I've been stuck on this for a while.

I'm using the latest versions of Eclipse Indigo for C++ and MinGW

Below are my cpp and h files:

This is my .cpp file

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "helloworldmodularized2.h"
using namespace std;



int  main()
{
    cat Earth;
    Earth.door_greeting();
}
```

Here is the .h file I am trying to include into my .cpp file

```cpp
//helloworldmodularized2.h

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class cat
{
public:
    void door_greeting();
};

void cat::door_greeting()
{
    cout << "Hello World!\n";
    cout << "Hello Door!\n";
    cout << "Hello Cat!\n";
}
```

The .h file presents no errors

The errors I am getting when trying to build the .cpp file are:

'cat' was not declared in this scope Line 11

'Earth' was not declared in this scope Line 12

Comment: Compiled fine with g++ . You probably have problem from Eclipse side.

Comment: That doesn't surprise me, I was pretty sure I was doing it right. Thanks very much. Any idea what the  problem with eclipse could be?

Comment: I do not work with eclipse. But if I was you, I would check file spells and make sure both cpp and h files are added to my project. Check file path. Check file capitalization if you are on unix base systems. If nothing did work, better to comment the whole your program and see if even a simple variable or function can be included at all!

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine.  Make sure the .h and .cpp are in the same directory.

Comment: Yes I checked this several times. I guess something is wrong with my Eclipse because I ran it in codeblocks and it worked. I guess I'll be using that from now on. Thank you for the answers guys

Comment: If both files are added to the project in Eclipse also, then it might be the builder settings.  Right-click the project name, choose "properties", select "C/C++ Build", and review the Builder Settings.  It's hard to know exactly what might be wrong with the information at hand - try playing with those settings.

Answer (score 0):

Goto project properties

1. under "c/c++ general" select "Paths and Symbols"
2. in include tab select language like GNU C++
3. click on Add
4. check "is a workspace path"
5. Click Workspace
6. Under your project name select source folder "src"
7. Apply and close